# Sybase ASE data selection from child proc

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a proc named proc1 Which does many DML operations and select's a data (many records). Now I need to create a proc named proc2( i have to create a tamp table named #hello) and  which will trigger proc1 and proc1 returns me 1000 records. how can i store it into #hello table with out modifying the proc1 , as it should not changed.
Please help me on this.below is example

```
create proc proc1
as 
begin
select * form table
end

create proc proc2 
as 
begin
create table #hello
exec proc1
--how will i insert proc1 data in #hello table
select * from #hello
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Rob Verschoor's proxy table method: http://www.sypron.nl/proctab.html

That's a bit of set-up though, which will probably need your DBA, so it might be simpler to ask for the SP to be changed.